# How to pass variable from POST

Tags: php, html

I want to pass two variable from **POST**, one is the text I write and the other one is the result of a query with I already have.But for some reason I am not getting the variable values. Can you help me?

This is my first page:

```
<form method="post" action="EliminarGrupos.php">
              <label for="nomegrupo"><b>Editar nome do grupo 1 :</label</b><br>

             <?php 

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result66)){
                $result = $row['titulogrupo'];
                $_POST['nomegrupo'] = $result; //saving first variable


            ?>
          <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $result?>" name="grupo1" id="velhas"></td> //saving second variable
           <?php } ?>


           <input type="submit" name="submit_x" data-inline="true" value="Submeter">
              </form>
```

This is my second page where I want the variables to appear

```
$variable = $_POST['nomegrupo'];
$variable2 = $_POST['grupo1'];
```

Comment: So you posted the form and then what? Did the data come through?

Comment: Setting `$_POST['nomegrupo']` doesn't mean that it will be available later.

Comment: You need to give your `$_POST` elements a **name** attribute on the form. This is what gives the `$_POST` its information, which it retrieves from **value**, not **placeholder**.

Comment: dude, obviously I used echo $variable and echo $variable2

Comment: can you post an example @ObsidianAge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `placeholder` attribute is for display purposes only. You need to set the `value` attribute to have it sent to the server.

To send a second value, just use a second `<input>` element. If you don't want it visible, set `type` attribute to `hidden`.

In addition, you are expecting an associative array from `mysqli_fetch_array()` which is not going to happen. Your HTML had a number of errors in it, which I think I've fixed below. You always need to escape output with `htmlspecialchars()`. You should separate your HTML and your PHP as much as possible.

```
<?php
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result66);
$titulogrupo = htmlspecialchars($row["titulogrupo"]);
?>

<form method="post" action="EliminarGrupos.php">
    <label for="velhas"><b>Editar nome do grupo 1 :</b></label><br/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="" name="grupo1" id="velhas"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="nomegrupo" value="<?=$titulogrupo?>"/>
    <button type="submit" name="submit_x" data-inline="true">Submeter</button>
</form>
```

Comment: yeah but the first POST(which as nothing to do with the input text) I make doesn't come throw on the next page

Answer (score 0):

You get the `$_POST` data from the form submission, specfically from the `name` attributes. This is what gives the `$_POST` its information, which it retrieves from `value`, not `placeholder`, as you have it now.

`<input name="grupo1" value="one">` will make `$_POST['grupo1']` equal to `one`.

You also shouldn't set the `$_POST` variable on page 1 as you are currently doing, and should make the unchanged variable from the database call a `hidden` field:

**Page 1:**

```
<form method="post" action="EliminarGrupos.php">
  <label for="nomegrupo"><b>Editar nome do grupo 1 :</label>
  <?php 
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result66)){
      $result = $row['titulogrupo'];
  ?>
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $result; ?>" name="grupo1" id="grupo1">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $result; ?>" name="titlogrupo" id="titlogrupo">
  <?php } ?>
  <input type="submit" name="submit_x" data-inline="true" value="Submeter">
</form>
```

**Page 2:**

```
$variable1 = $_POST['titulogrupo']; // $row['titulogrupo']
$variable2 = $_POST['grupo1']; // Form input
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: There is `name="grupo1"` in the original question.